# Error in NetLogo: Nothing named x has been defined

Tags: netlogo

I exported a landscape from NetLogo. I imported this same landscape in Netlogo. From this landscape, I added another global variable specific to patches "residency-time":

```
globals [
list-of-polygons ]

patches-own [ 
area-ha
residency-time 
]
```

I created a function to assign a value of residency time to each polygon in my landscape

```
to assign-residency-times
set list-of-polygons ([ID-polygon] of patches)
set list-of-polygons remove-duplicates list-of-polygons 
set list-of-polygons remove 0 list-of-polygons
print sort list-of-polygons

foreach list-of-polygons [ 
ask patches with [ ID-polygon = ? ] [ 
if all? patches [pcolor = green] [ 
set residency-time exp(1.02 * area-ha) ]

.... ] ]
```

I don't understand why I have this error message : `Nothing named area-ha has been defined`. However, I defined `area-ha` dans `patches-own`. 
In addition, when I inspect a patch, all global variables specific to patches disappeared (see figure below) !

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Hi Pierre, Have you defined the ha_area in a setup procedure ?

Comment: Thanks Delaye for your answer. No, I have not defined the area-ha in a setup procedure. I only defined a procedure which calculates the area of each polygon and the area value corresponds with the variable `area-ha`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Pierre, what's happening when you try to initialize area-ha? for sure when you define a global it's not an agent or patch variable... to your case it seems area_ha need to be a patch variable.

Comment: where precisely in the sequence of events here does “when I inspect a patch, all global variables specific to patches disappeared” occur? that seems quite strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I only have 45 reputation, so I can't just post a comment. But: It looks like you haven't defined ID-polygon as a patch-variable. This may be causing a problem earlier on in your code, and that may cause the code never to compile which would mean that patch vars are never actually added to patches in the "Interface" view.

This is assuming that you haven't defined a patch reporter called ID-polygon, of course. It's hard to tell without the full code.